# Loop through each row value and return column name

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table below. I would like to return in the haves column for each row in the table, column names where row values equals one, using python and pandas.

```
Location        House      car    Toys              haves
x                   1        1       3         House, Car
y                   2        1       1          Car, toys
```

Comment: Isn't that what you already have? (minus some casing differences) ? Or are you saying you want to generate that *haves* column from the existing columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First compare values by [`eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) (`==`) with [`dot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html) product with columns names and last remove last separator values by [`rstrip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.rstrip.html) if performance is important

```
df['haves'] = df.eq(1).dot(df.columns + ', ').str.rstrip(', ')
#solution with omiting first column
#df['haves'] = df.iloc[:, 1:].eq(1).dot(df.columns[1:] + ', ').str.rstrip(', ')
print (df)
  Location  House  car  Toys       haves
0        x      1    1     3  House, car
1        y      2    1     1   car, Toys
```

**Details**:

```
print (df.eq(1))
   Location  House   car   Toys
0     False   True  True  False
1     False  False  True   True

print (df.eq(1).dot(df.columns + ', '))
0    House, car, 
1     car, Toys, 
dtype: object
```

**Performance**: depends of number of `1` values, number of columns and rows, but because `dot` is vectorized it is faster like loop solutions:

```
#2k rows
df = pd.concat([df] * 1000, ignore_index=True)

In [183]: %timeit df['haves'] = df.eq(1).dot(df.columns + ', ').str.rstrip(', ')
2.65 ms ± 34.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

#working if no missing values 
In [184]: %timeit df['haves'] = [x.rstrip(', ') for x in df.eq(1).dot(df.columns + ', ')]
2.43 ms ± 38.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

#jpp answer
In [185]: %timeit df['haves'] = [', '.join(df.columns[1:][idx]) for idx in df.iloc[:, 1:].eq(1).values]
86.5 ms ± 4.32 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

#Naga Kiran removed answer
In [186]: %timeit df['have'] = df.apply(lambda x: ','.join(x[x.eq(1)].index),1)
813 ms ± 8.66 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: Even though your solutions are faster, are you *sure* it's not still an underlying Python-level loop? My understanding is contiguous memory blocks are not possible with string operations / `object` dtype, including `str` method accessor.

Comment: @jpp - Hard question, really. Maybe it is possible check by [prun](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-prun), but never do it before.

Comment: Worked! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you need to create the `haves` series, you can use a list comprehension:

```
df['haves'] = [', '.join(df.columns[1:][idx]) for idx in df.iloc[:, 1:].eq(1).values]

print(df)

  Location  House  car  Toys       haves
0        x      1    1     3  House, car
1        y      2    1     1   car, Toys
```

I don't believe this task is easily vectorisable since you can have a variable number of values satisfying your condition, and your result will be an `object` dtype series.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way which is only a little slower than the dot method and may be easier to understand.  It does use numpy to create the cols array which speeds things up considerably vs. just using df.columns as a list.

```
import numpy as np

# numpy array of dataframe column names
cols = np.array(df.columns)
# boolean array to mark where dataframe values equal 1
b = (df.values == 1)
# list comprehension to join column names for each boolean row result
df['haves'] = [', '.join(cols[(row_index)]) for row_index in b]
```